# How to use doxygen to copy documentation from a non-exported c++ class

Tags: c++, doxygen

i am trying to document a C++ project that is composed like this:

I have class A with a lot of documented code with doxygen.

Then i create via a wrapper script a new class B
that uses class A and exposes just a few of A's public methods in a 1-to-1 way:

```
A.h
---
class A {
public:
 /*! 
 * \brief Awesomw A method
 *  This method will be used in B
 */
 void someAfunc();
}


B.h
----
class A;
class B {
private:
 A *m_pA;
public:
 void someAfunc();
}

B.cpp
-----
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>
/*!
\copydoc A::someAfunc() 
*/
void B::someAfunc()
{
   m_pA->someAfunc();
}
```

If i run doxygen i can get the documentation for both classes A and B with the same content for someAfunc() method,

What i am trying to do is to **not** generate doxygen documentation for class A.

If i try to use EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS i will just get the class B generated but unfortunately the someAfunc() will not be documented.

I am using doxygen 1.9.1 on Linux

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, though a bit uncommon way of providing methods (I think).

There is no real simple way to accomplish this, but digging a bit in my box of tricks and for the provided example:

**A.h**

```
class A {
public:
 /*
  * [A_someAfunc_brief]
  Awesome A method.
  * [A_someAfunc_brief]
  *
  * [A_someAfunc]
  This method will be used in B
  * [A_someAfunc]
 */

 /*!
  * \brief
  * \snippet{doc} A.h  A_someAfunc_brief
  *
  * \snippet{doc} A.h  A_someAfunc
 */
 void someAfunc();
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>
/*!
 * \brief
 * \snippet{doc} A.h  A_someAfunc_brief
 *
 * \snippet{doc} A.h  A_someAfunc
*/
void B::someAfunc()
{
   m_pA->someAfunc();
}
```

**Doxyfile**

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS=A
QUIET=YES
EXAMPLE_PATH=.
```

I first wanted to go for:

```
 /*
  * [A_someAfunc]
  \brief Awesome A method.

  This method will be used in B
  * [A_someAfunc]
 */
```

but this gave some problems with the `\brief` command due to the moment of processing the `snippet{doc}` and `\brief` commands.
I also looked at the possibility:

```
 /*!
  * \brief
  * [A_someAfunc]
  Awesome A method.

  This method will be used in B
  * [A_someAfunc]
 */
```

but this gave some problems with the `[...]` part in the `class A` when this was included.

Comment: Hello @albert thanks for your response and your time, i will give the solution you propose a try but i think i will not be able to use it actively since it "clutters" the documentation of A (in the source files) a bit too much for my taste. As for the uncommon way to provide methods iwould be glad to hear some alternatives :)

Comment: It is indeed a bit of a cluttered solution. I think the basic problem is 2 folded, when excluding A one cannot refer to it, so a work around is required and this workaround cannot handle e.g. the `\brief` (see also https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7688)so an extra cluttered solution is required.